# Can you use the type definition of a struct even though the struct is non-exported?

Tags: go

I'm currently using the New() function to create all my new Person structs. I'm also using the  Person type in another package as a return value of another function.

Is there a way to have the Person struct being non-exported but also being able to use just the type definition of the struct in other packages?

Thanks in advance! :)

```
package models

type Person struct {
    Username string
    Email    string
}
func New() Person{
    return Person{}
}
```

```
package test

func test() models.Person{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't want to expose the `Username` and `Email`? and want to access them by getter/setter outside the package?

Comment: Sorry, I probably worded my question improperly but, I was aiming for only having 1 way of creating the structs through the New() function rather than directly creating the struct based solely on the struct definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear that the Person struct can be unexported and used as a function's return value without receiving the following error: `cannot refer to unexported name person.person`.

You can, however, create a Person interface that is returned from the `New()` func that returns an unexported person struct that implements that interface:

```
package models

type Person interface {
    GetUsername() string
    GetEmail() string
}
type person struct {
    Username string
    Email    string
}
func (p person) GetUsername() string {
    return p.Username
}
func (p person) GetEmail() string {
    return p.Email
}
func New() Person{
    return person{}
}
```

Then the test package can use that interface as its return value:

```
package test

func test() person.Person {
    return person.New()
}
```

Any particular reason you would like to do it this way? A common pattern you will see in idiomatic Go code would be something like the following:

```
// person.go
package person

// Person ...
type Person struct {
    Username string
    Email    string
}

// New ...
func New() Person {
    return Person{
        Username: "username",
        Email:    "email",
    }
}


// person_test.go
package person

import "testing"

func TestNew(t *testing.T) {
    p := New()
    if p.Username != "something" {
        t.Error("error")
    }
}
```

Where the Person struct and its tests are contained in the same package and Person is an exported struct which avoids the following go-lint warning: `exported func New returns unexported type person.person, which can be annoying to use`

Useful resources for Go:

https://go.dev/

https://blog.golang.org/

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

https://dave.cheney.net/resources-for-new-go-programmers

Comment: Oh, my thinking was that, technically someone would be able to make a new struct directly using the struct definition rather than using the New() function. Hence, that's why I wanted only 1 way of creating the struct. I just started learning Go not too long ago, but thank you so much!  :)

Comment: No problem, @SamIAm. Please let me know if you have any questions or need clarification on anything in my answer. I've also added a resources section at the bottom with some links to some great Go content. I hope you're enjoying learning Go. It's a very pleasant and powerful language to use.

Comment: Yep, for sure! Thanks so much!